# Error: 'Port is Closed'

Tags: c#, serial-port

I have 2 forms form1&form2. Form1 contains a serial port. This port is opened in form load.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
           serialPort1.Open();
      }
```

I want to write to serial port through form2. For that I created a function in form1 for writing to serial port.

```
public void SerialPortValueUpdated()
   {
       byte[] head = new byte[1] { 0xAA };
       byte[] trail = new byte[1] { 0x55 };
       byte[] llen = new byte[1] { length };
       // head = Convert.ToByte(0xAA);
       //serialPort1.Open();
       serialPort1.Write(head, 0, 1);
       serialPort1.Write(llen, 0, 1);
       serialPort1.Write(trail, 0, 1);
   }
```

and called this function from form2 like this

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
Form1 F = new Form1();
F.SerialPortValueUpdated();
```

}
But when I calling this function I get an error that 'Port is closed'. How can I solve this.
 Please help me.

Comment: how are you showing Form2 are you using Show or Showdialog in Form1?

Comment: form2 f2=new form2();f2.show();

Comment: f2.Show or f2.ShowDialog ?

Comment: private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            int bytes = serialPort1.BytesToRead;

            serialPort1.Read(byte_buffer, 0, bytes);

            if (byte_buffer[0] == startup)
            {

                Form2 f2 = new Form2();
                f2.Show();
               }
        }

Comment: please take your time and look around the FAQ section of this site and please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As was stated in the other answer you are creating a new Form1 in your Buttons click event instead of using the Form that you have already opened the serial port with. In my systems I use a separate class to encapsulate the communication logic as was mentioned in the other answer. But since this seems to be a simple application and your existing Form1 as knowledge of your Form2 since it created it, just pass form1 as the Owner of Form2, that way you can access the function you are wanting.

i.e.

```
f2 = new Form2();
f2.Show(this); // or f2.ShowDialog(this) if you want f2 to be Modal
```

You would then access it in your Form2's Button Click something like this.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   ((Form1)this.Owner).SerialPortValueUpdated();
}
```

---

**Form1**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Form2 f2;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        f2 = new Form2();
        f2.ShowDialog(this); // or f2.Show(this) if you want f2 to be non Modal
    }
    public void SerialPortValueUpdated()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Test");
    }
}
```

**Form2**

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    Form3 f3;
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ((Form1)this.Owner).SerialPortValueUpdated();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        f3 = new Form3();
        f3.ShowDialog(this.Owner); 
    }
}
```

**Form3**

```
public partial class Form3 : Form
{
    public Form3()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ((Form1)this.Owner).SerialPortValueUpdated();
    }
}
```

Comment: When try to access the function from form2's button click, am getting an error that 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object'.

Comment: This gets back to the question I asked you earlier, How are you showing your Form2, I am using an overload of the Show Method to pass the owner to Form2, if you will notice the **f2.show(this);** statement. you have something similar in your code somewhere, make it look the same.

Comment: f2 = new Form2();
            f2.ShowDialog(F1);

Comment: try f2.ShowDialog(this);

Comment: when I try f2.showDialog(this),getting the error 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object'.

Comment: I will put a simplistic example into my answer, it does work.

Comment: @DPM you really should try to debug `NullReferenceExceptions` yourself - it's really hard for us to guess your code

Comment: I have one more doubt If I want to access that function from form3, following this method is correct?

Comment: so,writing like ((Form1)f2.Owner).SerialPortValueUpdated(); is correct or not?

Comment: I am supposing that you are creating your form3 in your form1 if so just pass form1 as the owner like I showed for form2. without more information on where you are creating form3 I really can  not answer any better

Comment: am creating form3 in form2.

Comment: then something like this should work,  `f3.ShowDialog(this.Owner);` you are assigning the owner of form3 to form2's owner which is form1.  you would then use the same code in form3's click event as you have in form2. I will update my example

Comment: See my edit, this is as far as I would take it without creating a separate class to encapsulate your communication logic.

Comment: @MarkHall:if I declared a static variable in parent form, how can I access it from child form?

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that creating a new `Form1` will never open your port since the `Load` event will be called *when the form get's loaded*, and just newing up a form will not load or show it.

The easiest way to change this is to move the opening into the constructor.

So instead of

```
   private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
        serialPort1.Open();
   }
```

do

```
   public Form1()
   {
        serialPort1.Open();
   }
```

### The better approach

Having said that - using a `Form` just to do this kind of stuff is really not a solution. Instead use a simple class to do this and make it the responsibility of the caller to manage opening and closing (or if you really just want to write a few bytes then open and close it in your methods).

Comment: But I already tried this. But when I open serialport in public form1(), It shows another error that access to the port is denied..

Comment: then there is something wrong with your code/setup/port - I cannot possible know why with the information I have